# Insert GEOMETRY value using PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to insert GEOMETRY values into a table. For which I have a table with three columns as shown below:

Table: geo

```
create table geo
(
  p1 float,
  p2 float,
  Paths GEOMETRY
);
```

Input values: I have following values

```
p1 = 22.9901232886963
p2 = 87.5953903123242
```

**In SQL Server I used this**:

```
INSERT INTO geo(Paths)
VALUES (geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (22.9901232886963 87.5953903123242)'
,4326);
```

**Question**: Is there any function of GEOMETRY to calculate points in PostgreSQL 9.3 version?

Comment: Did you install PostGIS as an extension in your database? GEOMETRY is not a standard datatype in PostgreSQL, you have to create it (using PostGIS).

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Yeah! I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me by referring: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html.

The function:

```
point(point(double precision, double precision);
```

So I need to convert the function: using ::geometry

Finally the insert statement looks like:

```
insert into geo values(22.9901232886963 87.5953903123242,
point(22.9901232886963 87.5953903123242)::geometry);
```

Am I right?